# How to convert string date into date format in sqlite

Tags: date, datetime, sqlite

I need to find the average age  but my DOB is stored in the format Month,day,year(eg:-May,2,1986) in my sqlite database .

How can i convert from May,2,1986 into date format to find the age?

Regards
Nikil

Comment: Are you looking at a solution in SQLite itself?

Comment: yup i need the solution in sqlite .

Comment: Are the month names spelled out in full, or are they limited to 3 characters?  Is there really a comma between month and day?

Comment: @Catcall Yes months are spelt out in full and there is comma between month and day .

Answer (score 2):

This solution only considers the year, not the month + day (which you can add to it).

```
SELECT
   DATE('now') -
   CAST(
      SUBSTR(birth_date,-4) || '-' ||
      CASE SUBSTR(birth_date,0,LENGTH(birth_date)-8)
         WHEN 'January' THEN 1
         WHEN 'February' THEN 2
         WHEN 'March' THEN 3
         WHEN 'April' THEN 4
         WHEN 'May' THEN 5
         WHEN 'June' THEN 6
         WHEN 'July' THEN 7
         WHEN 'August' THEN 8
         WHEN 'September' THEN 9
         WHEN 'October' THEN 10
         WHEN 'November' THEN 11
         WHEN 'December' THEN 12
      END || '-' ||
      SUBSTR(birth_date, 6,1)
   AS DATE)
FROM foo;
```

This will give you `26.0`.

Answer (score 0):

try this
declare @dob varchar(200)
set @dob = 'May,2,1986'
select convert(datetime, @dob)

if this doesnt work you will need to substring the year month and day and then assign them to a variable together and substract with current date(getdate()) to get your age.

Comment: i think Convert() does not exist in sqlite . How can i convert Name of month to its equivalent number ie May as 5 if i am taking the second approach?