# SQLite Data Time Function

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I currently have a timestamp in this format `Tue Jun 03 17:17:05 +0000 2014` in one column in my table. I want to count the number of records happening in specific intervals (15 minutes). I have tried to follow the answer found in [Group records by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110341/group-records-by-time). Although my timestamp is in a different format and I haven't seen any support function available in SQLite to convert this. Is this possible in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SQLite date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) can be used to convert a timestring to a canonical format, or to a Julian Day Number. Unfortunately, the SQLite date and time functions only accept timestring in a limited number of formats:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
```

If your timestring format has fixed field widths, you can use the `substr` function and the `||` string concatenation operator to convert it to a format SQLite understands. You'll have to use a `case` expression to convert the month names to numbers; [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337751/33252).

Answer (score 0):

You may use NEW_TIME in Oracle to convert the time to a specific timezone. Here is an example. This example is converting SYSDATE from PDT to GMT.

`SELECT NEW_TIME (SYSDATE, 'PDT', 'GMT') FROM DUAL;`

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257324/oracle-how-to-add-minutes-to-a-timestamp) is detailing how to add required minutes to your timestamp.