# How to convert a date of the format 'April 9, 2013' into the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, dataformat

I have been trying to convert a column consisting of dates in the format 'April 9, 2013' into
the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' which would result in '2013-04-09' in SQLite.

I have tried using the 'date' & 'strftime' function but get null as a result

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), show your schema CREATE, sample data via "INSERT", and your query.

Comment: Similar question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336565/how-to-convert-string-date-into-date-format-in-sqlite). Before a solution emerges, maybe you can use something from that. But your solution would probably be simpler using an external program to manipulate the data. SQLite does not have native functions you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates **always** are in the form of `Monthname[space]day[comma]year` this should work. Assuming your field name is `dt` and table name `test` here, **change as needed**.

```sql
SELECT
        SUBSTR(dt, instr(dt, ',') + 2) || '-' ||
        printf('%02d',
         CASE substr(dt, 0, instr(dt, ' '))
             WHEN 'January' THEN 1
             WHEN 'February' THEN 2
             WHEN 'March' THEN 3
             WHEN 'April' THEN 4
             WHEN 'May' THEN 5
             WHEN 'June' THEN 6
             WHEN 'July' THEN 7
             WHEN 'August' THEN 8
             WHEN 'September' THEN 9
             WHEN 'October' THEN 10
             WHEN 'November' THEN 11
             WHEN 'December' THEN 12
          END)  || '-' ||
        printf('%02d',
        substr(
         substr(dt, 0, instr(dt, ',')),
         instr(substr(dt, 0, instr(dt, ',')), ' ')+1
         )) as mydate
FROM test
```

```
+------------+
|   mydate   |
+------------+
| 2013-04-09 |
+------------+
```